# Openshift - Cannot connect to mysql gear

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge, openshift-gears

My app was stuck on connecting to Database gear for almost few day now.
I have tried almost 2 days to search, but it seem no luck.
Could anyone help!

What I have tried:

1. ssh in to main gear (application gear) is ok, but fail when trying manually connect to mysql.

   $mysql

   ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '559e8e625973cad7d10001b5-jobboardkh.rhcloud.com' (111)
2. telnet

   $telnet  559e8e625973cad7d10001b5-jobboardkh.rhcloud.com 48986
   Trying 54.159.182.108...
   telnet: connect to address 54.159.182.108: Connection refused
3. port-forward on my local and I tried to connect as it worked before, but now it's not work
4. ssh to mysql gear also not able to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have waited to get the support from Openshift for several days, but at last I decided to remove out that database gear and recreated it. So all my data was lost.

resolution for preventing database gear is down and data will lost, is to have a daily backup schedule for database and store it in the main gear.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't ssh into the gear then the gear probably isn't running. Try restarting the MySQL gear via:
`rhc cartridge restart -a {appName} -c mysql-5.1`

Comment: Yes, I did restart mysql cartridge many time. I also had stop and start too. more when I  run  `rhc app-show -a {appName}  --gear` it showed that the database gear already started. but when do port-forward still can not connect.

Comment: @fangli then you really need to contact OpenShift support.